# Use C# on a client to redirect TCP requests

Tags: c#, .net, networking, tcp

I have an enterprise case where workstations might send TCP requests to several known destinations. For example: `host1.domain.local:1234` and `host2.domain.local:1234`. I need to install a .NET client on the workstations that, when running, will redirect traffic for these destinations to other endpoints. For example: `myProxyHost1.domain.local:1234` and `myProxyHost2.domain.local:1234`. We are considering editing the hosts file, but that feels clunky and could leave the system in a dirty state if our client crashes. We would rather have our client listen on these ports and redirect any TCP traffic appropriately. I'm hoping this is possible, given that products like Fiddler exist. How can I redirect traffic like this in C#?

Comment: Fiddler *does not* redirect *TCP* traffic... It is simply an HTTP proxy which requires 10 lines of code to start with (Indeed remaining thousands of lines of code in Fiddler is what makes it useful, but plain HTTP proxy is not much code in itself).

Comment: TCP and IP have no idea about domain names, which is at the application-layer.

Comment: You want a Two Port Application which listens on one TCP port and forwards to second TCP connection.  The first Port the application opens a listener.  The second port the application is a client that connects to other hosts.

Answer (score 0):

If developing a .NET client is not the main criteria you could check about using a web server working as TCP load balancer. It's not a .NET client as you asked but it might solve the problem.

Take a look at Nginx docs to see if it meet your requirements: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/

You could use the proxy pass directive, an example from the docs:

```
stream {

   server {
       listen     12346;
       #TCP traffic will be forwarded to the specified server
       proxy_pass backend.example.com:12346;
   }

   # ...
```

}